# Django-compressor offline AttributeError on upgrade to Dj1.7

Tags: django-1.7, django-compressor

Recently upgraded a project to Django 1.7, and django-compressor to version 1.4. Before this upgrade, compressor worked without a hitch.

Now when I run `python manage.py compress` (with or without `-f`) I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'child_nodelists'`. I found a similar issue discussed [here](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/542), but they seem to conclude that this issue arises when using `{{ block.super }}` in the base template.

However there is nowhere in my template structure that uses `{{ block.super }}`. I have tried removing all references to the compressor in all templates, but the error still occurs.

Anyone else run into this? What was your solution?